# For IEEE papers with Part 1 and Part 2 do I need to submit both parts at the same time?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, ieee

Sometimes in IEEE magazines I see Part 1 in one issue and Part 2 in the next issue.
How does this work when writing and submitting? Do I need to submit both parts at the same time or does IEEE decide to split it? Can there be more than a one issue delay between Part 1 and Part 2?

As part of my PhD requirements, I have to write two papers, one with a review of the latest papers in the field and another with my contributions. Many Part 1 and Part 2 papers are organised like that.

My two papers cannot be published at the same time and unless the first part is published, University will not consider approving my contributions.

Comment: Why can you not submit them as two completely separate papers? Then you don't have to worry about this issue. You can still link them by a similar sounding title, e.g. "Topic X: recent developments" for the review and "Topic X: a novel method to improve sensor characteristics" for your contribution.

Comment: Ask the editor how you should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The way you phrased your post is a bit misleading, I think.  There are two possible answers.

**Answer-1**
It seems that your supervisor/university requires you to first publish a literature review/survey followed by one or more contributions.  This is quite the norm in engineering and computer science.   In practice, in their first year, students conduct and write a literature review/survey, and identify a number of research questions.  They then submit the survey for review. At the same time, they start work on their first contribution or research question.   By the time they complete the first contribution, the survey paper may have received feedback.  Students then revise the survey paper, and finalize their first contribution.  At this point, they have two papers in review.   They then start on the second contribution, and the cycle repeats.

**Answer-2**
There are papers whereby authors break up a huge paper into two parts.  The first part deals with theory.  The second part deals with the application of said theory.  For these papers, both parts are submitted simultaneously.

An example from IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing:

- Parallel and Distributed Methods for Constrained Nonconvex
  Optimization—Part I: Theory.
- Parallel and Distributed Methods for Constrained Nonconvex
  Optimization-Part II: Applications in Communications and Machine
  Learning

Answer (score 0):

You need to see what your predecessors did. I am concerned for you based on your question because I do not know any IEEE transactions or even conferences that accepts review / survey papers. There is the ACM Surveys, but the authors there are often very well known people who write about their research field of the last decade. The IEEE magazines are aimed at practitioners for their readership and the literature review of a typical Ph. D. topic would be usually too specialized.

Also, any IEEE transaction will usually want to have a "related work" section in all papers, so splitting it up like you are supposed to do is really difficult.

I am in Computer Science and my answer might be too discipline dependent. But, to repeat myself, I am afraid that your university is making your life really complicated. Your predecessors must have found a way around a restriction that might make sense in Philosophy or Theology, but not in Engineering or the Sciences. Find out what they did and follow their example.

Comment: 'I do not know of any IEEE transactions..' -- this is incorrect.  Many IEEE Trans. accept surveys.   There is also the IEEE communications surveys & tutorials.